# Xcode - Something may not respond to

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm getting some warnings that somethings may not respond to a function.

```
#import "Lane.h"
#import "TrafficController.h"


@implementation Lane
@synthesize controller;


-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [controller registerLane:self]; -- 'TrafficController' may not respond to '-registerlane'
    srandom(time(NULL));
    [self start];
}

-(void)start
{
    long newStartTime = random() % 200;
    carStartTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:newStartTime / 1000.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [carStartTimer retain];
}

-(void)startTimerFired: (NSTimer*)timer
{
    //pick a random number of milliseconds to fire again at

    long newStartTime = random() % 1500 + 500;

    [timer setFireDate:[NSDate datewWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:newStartTime / 1000.0]];
    [controller startCarFromLane:self]; - 'TrafficController' may not respond to '-startCarFromLane'

    NSLog(@"Starting new car");
}

-(void)stop
{
    [carStartTimer invalidate];
    [carStartTimer release];
    carStartTimer = nil;
}

@end
```

Does it mean that those functions arent declared in this or other header file? Or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TrafficController.h, do you have a line like:

```
-(void) registerLane: (type) variablename;
```

If you don't, you should have

Comment: No. But my TrafficController.m file has it tough.

Comment: You still need it in the .h so that other classes which are attempting to use that functionality, know what it's meant to look like. That's what the #import is for.

Comment: No worries mate, enjoy your traffic game!

Answer (score 0):

Do what @Dave says and let the complier know about your methods in your header file.

You can also quiet that message by manipulating the order of the methods in your implementation file. If the compiler has already seen the method (in this case `-(void)registerLane:`), then it won't bellyache when you call it later, even if it's not in your .h file.

That way you can have internal methods that aren't advertised as available in your .h but you can call them internally without compiler warnings. BUT, in most cases this is a mistake and you probably just forget to put it in the .h file.